# C and C++ --- undefined reference to

Tags: c++, c, undefined-symbol

i need help!

I've implemented a .cpp program in the next path: home/virginia/android/vlc/src/input/virtual.cpp

```
    /*
    *  virtual.cpp
    */
    #include <stdlib.h>

    #include <jni.h>
    #include <math.h>

    #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/imgproc/types_c.h>
    #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h>
    #include <opencv2/photo/photo.hpp>

    #include <android/log.h>

    extern "C" {
       #include "virtual.h"
    }
    #define  LOG_TAG    "VLC - Imagen 3D -  JNI"
    #define  LOGI(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
    #define  LOGE(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)

    using namespace cv;
    using namespace std;

    extern "C" int camino(void){... }
```

This programs calls to the opencv functions.

virtual.h ( home/virginia/android/vlc/src/input/virtual.h)

```
/*
* virtual.h
*/
    #ifndef __VIRTUAL_H
    #define __VIRTUAL_H

    int camino(void);

    #endif /*__VIRTUAL_H*/
```

But the problem is that i need to call to "camino" function from decoder.c (( home/virginia/android/vlc/src/input/decoder.c):

```
#include "virtual.h"

#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
# include "config.h"
#endif
#include <assert.h>

...
static void DecoderPlayVideo( decoder_t *p_dec, picture_t *p_picture,
                              int *pi_played_sum, int *pi_lost_sum ){

...
            int res = camino();
            msg_Warn( p_dec, "Llamada a virtualJNI devuelve %d", &res );
            vout_PutPicture( p_vout, p_picture );
...
}
...
```

I'm getting the next error:

```
/home/virginia/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ../vlc/android/src/.libs/libvlccore.a(decoder.o): in function DecoderDecodeVideo:../../src/input/decoder.c:1501: error: undefined reference to 'camino'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libvlcjni.so] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/virginia/android/vlc-android'
make: *** [vlc-android/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libvlcjni.so] Error 2
```

What am i doing wrong? Thanks so much

Comment: Why do you have ` extern "C" ` in the definition?

Comment: You should decide if you are programming in C or C++, in the first place. Then follow the conventions of that language. For example, in C++ you don't write `int camino(void);`, but `int camino();`. I don't even know if the former is valid - you just _don't_ write that.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with putting void there. It's not considered good style in C++, and I don't do it, but it's not wrong.

Comment: Shouldn't you put the `extern "C"` on the function definition in `virtual.h`? When you include the header in `decoder.c` it also needs to know the function has `C` linkage.

Comment: @Neil Ok but the "C and C++" in the title just adds confusion. It should be explained: "I'm calling a C module from a C++ program", or something like that.

Comment: You aren't linking properly.  Your program doesn't know what `camino` is, because the code has not been linked in.

Comment: @Blastfurnace I'm not a C expert so I may be wrong, but the c file doesn't need to see that it is using C linkage because that is the default in C.

Comment: @KirkBackus camino is defined virtual.cpp so why is it not linked in?

Comment: @NeilKirk: An effect of the `extern "C"` is to turn off `C++` name mangling. That may be why it's failing to link. I'm not actually sure...

Comment: @Blastfurnace cpp files will need to see the extern "C" to turn off name mangling, but c file is compiled as C which does not have name mangling. It is more usual to put extern "C" in the header file in question, surrounded by #ifdef __cplusplus, rather than on each include of the header file, as you may forget to do that. Maybe that is even causing the problem.

Comment: @NeilKirk: You're right, I finally noticed the file suffix on `decoder.c`.

Comment: `decoder.o` needs to be linked with `virtual.o`. Check your link line, or your makefile, or your unspecified build tool of choice.

Comment: @NeilKirk It is not linked in on `decoder.c`.  The code is compiling correctly for `virtual.cpp`, but it needs to be linked in the `decoder.c` to use.  At least, `decoder.c` is where the error is coming from.

Comment: Changing the contents in the header file to extern "C" int camino(void) worked.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the `extern "C"` stuff, it's not recommended to do this:

```
extern "C" {
   #include "virtual.h"
}
```

Instead, you should put it in the header:

```
/*
* virtual.h
*/
    #ifndef __VIRTUAL_H
    #define __VIRTUAL_H

    #ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
    #endif

    int camino();

    #ifdef __cplusplus
    }
    #endif

    #endif /*__VIRTUAL_H*/
```

You'll see this in almost all headers that are meant to be shared between C and C++.

As for your real problem, you'll have to show us the actual linker command, not just the error, but it looks like `virtual.o` isn't being linked into your program, and possibly isn't being built.

Comment: I've changed the header file, virtual.h. 
I know that it is linker error, but i have some files and i don't know how link the opencv libraries.

Compile.sh file: https://github.com/mstorsjo/vlc-android/blob/master/compile.sh
Makefile file: https://github.com/mstorsjo/vlc-android/blob/master/Makefile
configure.sh file: https://github.com/mstorsjo/vlc-android/blob/master/configure.sh

Comment: In configure.sh, i've modified the next lines:
CPPFLAGS="-I${ANDROID_NDK}/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++${CXXSTL}/include -I${ANDROID_NDK}/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++${CXXSTL}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/include -I/usr/local/include"

LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -L${ANDROID_NDK}/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++${CXXSTL}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI} -L/usr/local/lib"

Thanks for the help!